# Scrapy duplicate username result

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am learning to use Scrapy for a project. I am facing a problem when I am trying to collect the username, no personal information, of a post in a thread. The website that I am using to collect data is https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/172311-lego-star-wars-2020-set-discussion-read-first-post/. By looking at the HTML of the page, I found that the username is stored in this part of the code.

```
<a href="https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/profile/172939-backtobricks/" data-ipshover="" 
data-ipshover-target="https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/profile/172939-backtobricks/&amp;do=hovercard&amp;
referrer=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.eurobricks.com%252Fforum%252Findex.php%253F%252Fforums%252Ftopic%252F172311-lego-star-wars-2020-set-discussion-read-first-post%252F" 
title="Go to BacktoBricks's profile" class="ipsType_break" id="ips_uid_1558_18">BacktoBricks</a>
```

So, to get the username info I used the following command

```
 response.xpath("//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()")
```

The problem is that as result I get:

```
[<Selector xpath="//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()" data='MKJoshA'>,
 <Selector xpath="//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()" data='MKJoshA'>,
 <Selector xpath="//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()" data='JekPorkchops'>,
 <Selector xpath="//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()" data='JekPorkchops'>,
 <Selector xpath="//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()" data='Mandalorianknight'>,
 <Selector xpath="//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()" data='Brick Cucumber'>,
 <Selector xpath="//a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()" data='Brick Cucumber'>,
```

As you can see the username sometimes is dupplicate even if the user has just post once.
Any idea on how to solve it? Is the only information that has this problem because I have collect also the information about the countries and I haven't face any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What happens?**

You try to select every element with the pattern `a[@class='ipsType_break']` and there is more than one per `username`:

Try to use a more specific `xpath`:

```
//strong/a[@class='ipsType_break']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can store the response.text into a set that will give you unique results

```
names = {} #set of names
for name in names:
   names.add(name) #add element to names
```